# Css make an image fit in a 100% wide div

Tags: html, css, image, width

I am completely new to css and I need some help

Here is the problem:
I have a 1600 pixel wide image and a 100 % wide div.

Is there a way to make the image fit into the div so that there wil be no horizontal scroll bar and the remainder of the image is cut off at the right side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should write your css with %(responsive coding). In that case you can set image ***width:100% and overflow:hidden***. This is *the way to make the image fit into the div so that there wil be no horizontal scroll bar and the remainder of the image is cut off at the right side*

Answer (score 2):

use

```
{background-position:cover;}
```

to the image. it will be set without any scrollbar.